# Why is my eventlistener not listening to some tiles of the map?

Tags: leaflet, javascript, html, event-listener

I have a Leaflet map on a page that I developed as part of a school assignment. The ID of the map element is `mapid`. I have added mouse listeners to `mapid`.  When I enter the area of `mapid` on my page, the listener fires a hover event and on most of the surface of `mapid` the listener tracks clicks. But there are a few patches of blind spots on `mapid`, where the mouse listener for some reasons leaves the area of `mapid` and enters the area of another element without an ID although the mouse cursor has indeed not left the area of `mapid`.

Here is my HTML code:

```
<html xml:lang="de" lang="de">

<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <!-- Latest compiled and minified CSS -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.css"
        integrity="sha512-xwE/Az9zrjBIphAcBb3F6JVqxf46+CDLwfLMHloNu6KEQCAWi6HcDUbeOfBIptF7tcCzusKFjFw2yuvEpDL9wQ=="
        crossorigin="" />
    <!-- Make sure you put this AFTER Leaflet's CSS -->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/leaflet.js"
        integrity="sha512-GffPMF3RvMeYyc1LWMHtK8EbPv0iNZ8/oTtHPx9/cc2ILxQ+u905qIwdpULaqDkyBKgOaB57QTMg7ztg8Jm2Og=="
        crossorigin=""></script>
    <script src="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/esri-leaflet@2.0.8"></script>
    <script src="https://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet.js"></script>

    <script src="https://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet-geocoder.js">
    </script>

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
        href="https://cdn-geoweb.s3.amazonaws.com/esri-leaflet-geocoder/0.0.1-beta.5/esri-leaflet-geocoder.css">



    <!-- jQuery library -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

    <!-- Latest compiled JavaScript -->
    <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
    <div id="mapid" style="width: 1287px; height: 300px; position: relative; outline: none;"
        class="leaflet-container leaflet-touch leaflet-fade-anim leaflet-grab leaflet-touch-drag leaflet-touch-zoom"
        tabindex="0">
        <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane">
                <div id="zoomOut" class="leaflet-layer " style="z-index: 1; opacity: 1;">
                    <div id="zoomOut" class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated"
                        style="z-index: 18; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);"><img alt=""
                            role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4093/2723.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(56px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4094/2723.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(312px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4093/2724.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(56px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4094/2724.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(312px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4092/2723.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-200px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4095/2723.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(568px, -91px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4092/2724.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-200px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4095/2724.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(568px, 165px, 0px); opacity: 1;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-shadow-pane"><img
                    src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"
                    class="leaflet-marker-shadow leaflet-zoom-animated" alt=""
                    style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 41px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(300px, 247px, 0px);">
            </div>
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane"><svg pointer-events="none" class="leaflet-zoom-animated"
                    width="720" height="480" viewBox="-60 -40 720 480"
                    style="transform: translate3d(-60px, -40px, 0px);">
                    <g>
                        <path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3"
                            stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#f03" fill-opacity="0.5"
                            fill-rule="evenodd"
                            d="M141.20355555554852,171.94704600190744a42,42 0 1,0 84,0 a42,42 0 1,0 -84,0 "></path>
                        <path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="#3388ff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3"
                            stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#3388ff" fill-opacity="0.2"
                            fill-rule="evenodd" d="M358 163L474 219L550 153z"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg></div>
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"><img
                    src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png"
                    class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" alt="" tabindex="0"
                    style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 25px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(300px, 247px, 0px); z-index: 247;">
            </div>
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tooltip-pane"></div>
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane">
                <div class="leaflet-popup  leaflet-zoom-animated"
                    style="opacity: 1; transform: translate3d(301px, 213px, 0px); bottom: -7px; left: -57px;">
                    <div class="leaflet-popup-content-wrapper"></div>
                    <div class="leaflet-popup-tip-container">
                        <div class="leaflet-popup-tip"></div>
                    </div><a class="leaflet-popup-close-button" href="#close">×</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated"
                style="transform: translate3d(1.04805e+06px, 697379px, 0px) scale(4096);"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="leaflet-control-container">
            <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left">
                <div id="leafletBar" class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control"><a id="zoomIn"
                        class="leaflet-control-zoom-in" href="#" title="Zoom in" role="button"
                        aria-label="Zoom in">+</a><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-out" href="#" title="Zoom out"
                        role="button" aria-label="Zoom out">−</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div>
            <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left"></div>
            <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right">
                <div class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-map-pane" style="transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tile-pane">
                <div class="leaflet-layer " style="z-index: 1; opacity: 1;">
                    <div class="leaflet-tile-container leaflet-zoom-animated"
                        style="z-index: 18; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px) scale(1);"><img alt=""
                            role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4400/2686.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(124px, 4px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4400/2685.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(124px, -252px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4399/2686.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-132px, 4px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4401/2686.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(380px, 4px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4400/2687.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(124px, 260px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4399/2685.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-132px, -252px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4401/2685.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(380px, -252px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4399/2687.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(-132px, 260px, 0px); opacity: 1;"><img
                            alt="" role="presentation"
                            src="https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/mapbox.streets/13/4401/2687.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw"
                            class="leaflet-tile leaflet-tile-loaded"
                            style="width: 256px; height: 256px; transform: translate3d(380px, 260px, 0px); opacity: 1;">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-shadow-pane"><img
                    src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-shadow.png"
                    class="leaflet-marker-shadow leaflet-zoom-animated" alt=""
                    style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 41px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(-78224px, 9814px, 0px);">
            </div>
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-overlay-pane"><svg pointer-events="none" class="leaflet-zoom-animated"
                    width="720" height="480" viewBox="-60 -40 720 480"
                    style="transform: translate3d(-60px, -40px, 0px);">
                    <g>
                        <path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="red" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3"
                            stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#f03" fill-opacity="0.5"
                            fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0"></path>
                        <path class="leaflet-interactive" stroke="#3388ff" stroke-opacity="1" stroke-width="3"
                            stroke-linecap="round" stroke-linejoin="round" fill="#3388ff" fill-opacity="0.2"
                            fill-rule="evenodd" d="M0 0"></path>
                    </g>
                </svg></div>
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-marker-pane"><img
                    src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.5.1/dist/images/marker-icon.png"
                    class="leaflet-marker-icon leaflet-zoom-animated leaflet-interactive" alt="" tabindex="0"
                    style="margin-left: -12px; margin-top: -41px; width: 25px; height: 41px; transform: translate3d(-78224px, 9814px, 0px); z-index: 9814;">
            </div>
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-tooltip-pane"></div>
            <div class="leaflet-pane leaflet-popup-pane"></div>
            <div class="leaflet-proxy leaflet-zoom-animated"
                style="transform: translate3d(1.12658e+06px, 687812px, 0px) scale(4096);"></div>
        </div>
        <div class="leaflet-control-container">
            <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-left">
                <div class="leaflet-control-zoom leaflet-bar leaflet-control"><a class="leaflet-control-zoom-in"
                        href="#" title="Zoom in" role="button" aria-label="Zoom in">+</a><a
                        class="leaflet-control-zoom-out" href="#" title="Zoom out" role="button"
                        aria-label="Zoom out">−</a></div>
            </div>
            <div class="leaflet-top leaflet-right"></div>
            <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-left"></div>
            <div class="leaflet-bottom leaflet-right">
                <div class="leaflet-control-attribution leaflet-control"><a href="https://www.mapbox.com/">Mapbox</a>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script>
        var mymap = L.map('mapid').setView([52.515803012883595, 13.38958740234375], 15);

        L.tileLayer(
            'https://api.tiles.mapbox.com/v4/{id}/{z}/{x}/{y}.png?access_token=pk.eyJ1IjoibWFwYm94IiwiYSI6ImNpejY4NXVycTA2emYycXBndHRqcmZ3N3gifQ.rJcFIG214AriISLbB6B5aw', {
                maxZoom: 18,
                attribution: 'Map data &copy; <a href="https://www.openstreetmap.org/">OpenStreetMap</a> contributors, ' +

                    id: 'mapbox.streets'
            }).addTo(mymap);
        var searchControl = new L.esri.Controls.Geosearch().addTo(mymap);

        var results = new L.LayerGroup().addTo(mymap);
        searchControl.on('results', function (data) {
            results.clearLayers();
            for (var i = data.results.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) {
                results.addLayer(L.marker(data.results[i].latlng).addEventListener('click', function (e) {
                    results.clearLayers();

                }))
            }
        });
    </script>
    <script src="script1.js" data-turbolinks-track="reload"></script>

    <script type=text/javascript src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.js"></script>    

</body>

</html>
```

This bit here is the JavaScipt code, that does the listening:

```
mapid = document.getElementById("mapid")
mapid.addEventListener("mouseover", function (event) {
    overFunction(event);
});
mapid.addEventListener("mouseout", function (event) {
    outFunction(event);
});

mapid.addEventListener("click", function (event) {
    focusFunction(event);
});

function overFunction(event) {
    mData = "hoveredOver,      mapid,       " + Date.now() + ",    " +
        event.clientX.toString() + "_" + event.clientY.toString()
    console.log(mData)
}

function outFunction(event) {
    mData = "hoveredAway,      mapid,       " + Date.now() + ",    " +
        event.clientX.toString() + "_" + event.clientY.toString()
    console.log(mData)
}

function focusFunction(event) {
    mData = "clickedOn,      mapid,         " + Date.now() + ",   " +
        event.clientX.toString() + "_" + event.clientY.toString()
    console.log(mData)
}
```

Here is what the outputs for the eventlisteners looks like:

```
Type of event    Element ID       timestamp       mouse coordinates

hoveredOver,     mapid,           1580381863148,   1238_449    
clickedOn,       mapid,           1580382072804,   1238_300
hoveredAway,     mapid,           1580382149916,   726_335
hoveredOver,          ,           1580382149918,   726_335
mouseClick,           ,           1580382153537,   726_340
```

As you can see, the third output says that I have hovered away from `mapid`. That's not true, as I had not left the area of `mapid`. And the last two outputs show that I entered and clicked on an element whose ID is basically an empty string. Why is this happening? How can I avoid it?

Comment: If you have HTML element `elem1` above  event listening element `elem2`, you will get `mouseout` event for `elem2` as soon mouse goes over `elem1`, and if `elem1` does not stop event propagation, you will get `mouseover` event for `elem2` right after that. Since this is purely HTML question, I'm voting to close it here.

Comment: And the answer is right at https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Element/mouseout_event : «`mouseout` is also delivered to an element if the cursor enters a child element, because the child element obscures the visible area of the element.»